# Lua table add an exception

Tags: gridview, lua, coronasdk, lua-table

How can I set a value in my grid (for example address : grille[4][5]) directly in a loop? I would like that grille[4][5].yScale and grille[4][5].xScale are smaller than the others.

```
grille = {}
 
local colonnes = 8
local lignes = 15
local variable = math.random(1, 10)
local rectx = 30
local recty = 30
local grillescaley = 0.35
local grillescalex = 0.35
local espacement = 2
local ecartgauche =10
local ecarthaut = 50
local image = "myx.png"

for i = 1, lignes do
    grille[i] = {};
    for k = 1, colonnes do 
        grille[i][k] = display.newImage(image)
        grille[i][k].yScale=0.35
        grille[i][k].xScale=0.35
        grille[i][k].alpha = 1
        grille[i][k].x = (k - 1) * (rectx + espacement) + ecartgauche
        grille[i][k].y = (i - 1) * (recty + espacement) + ecarthaut
end
end
```

Comment: Can you explain the issue and what you want more clearly?

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop, use an `if` block:

```
for k = 1, colonnes do  
    grille[i][k] = display.newImage(image)
    if k==5 and i==4 then
        grille[i][k].yScale=0.65 -- or whatever
        grille[i][k].xScale=0.65 -- or whatever
    else
        grille[i][k].yScale=0.35
        grille[i][k].xScale=0.35
    end
    grille[i][k].alpha = 1
    grille[i][k].x = (k - 1) * (rectx + espacement) + ecartgauche
    grille[i][k].y = (i - 1) * (recty + espacement) + ecarthaut
end
```